# HIMAWARI Datasets Cloud Properties for Specific Cloud Type Extraction

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm a newbie. I already downloaded the datasets and I'm about to extract cloud properties of a specific cloud type (Cirrus).
Using Phython, what specific codes should I write to set the condition CLTYPE = cirrus and also, how to set the condition to extract the properties {CLOT (cloud optical thickness), CLTH (cloud top height), CLTT (cloud top temerature), CLER (cloud effective radius)} under the condition that the cloud type is equal to cirrus?

Thank youu.

I did download the dataset from JAXA and I'm expecting to acquire or learn the code to define or set the condition of CLTYPE = cirruis and also the code to get the cloud properties for the set cloud type condition which is cirrus clouds. I think cirrus clouds is pixel number 1.